¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estos dos formas de reshape? np.reshape(arr) y arr.reshape()
Haciendo un ejercicio me encontré que se podía resolver de dos maneras y conseguir el mismo resultado:
array2 = array1.reshape(filas, columnas)

y
array2 = np.reshape(array1, (filas, columnas))

¿Es lo mismo y no hay diferencia entre las dos sintaxis? ¿O solo dio el mismo resultado por ser un ejercicio simple y cuando se aplica a algo mas complejo no es lo mismo?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

La diferencia más obvia es que numpy.reshape() es una función exportada por el paquete numpy mientras que numpy.ndarray.reshape() es un método de instancia de los arrays de numpy. Esto obviamente hace que se llamen de forma distinta, la primera simplemente recibe como primer argumento el array objetivo:
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.reshape(arr, (2, 2))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]

En el segundo caso, al ser un método de instancia, lo normal es llamarlo usando la notación punto usada para acceder a cualquier atributo/método de instancia, objeto.método(). En este caso el primer argumento es la propia instancia del objeto (self por convención) y es pasada automáticamente:
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> arr.reshape((2, 2))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]

y es equivalente a:
>>> np.ndarray.reshape(arr, (2, 2))

Otra diferencia mencionada en la documentación es que el método de instancia permite pasar las nuevas dimensiones como argumentos separados:
>>> arr.reshape(2, 2)

En cuanto al resultado final en tu ejemplo, es exactamente lo mismo. Internamente en ambos casos, en ultima instancia terminas llamando exactamente al mismo código. La función numpy.reshape está definida en numpy/numpy/_core/fromnumeric.py y básicamente hace esto:
return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

dónde _wrapfunc es:
def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    bound = getattr(obj, method, None)
    if bound is None:
        return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
    try:
        return bound(*args, **kwds)
    except TypeError:
        return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

Es decir, básicamente lo que hace numpy.reshape cuando el primer argumento es un numpy.ndarray es:
>>> getattr(arr, "reshape")((2, 2))

es decir, llamar a arr.reshape().
En definitiva, si los aplicas sobre un array son lo mismo, usar uno u otro es más que nada cuestión de cual te conviene más en cuanto a forma de ser llamados.
Quizás lo mas notable es que numpy.reshape acepta como primer argumento otros objetos array-like, no solo numpy.ndarray, por ejemplo, puedes pasarle una lista de Python:
>>> np.reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], (2, 2))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

